# Shouldnt Bast be able to defeat Apophis from years of fighting him in Apophis prison

Tags: rick-riordan, the-kane-chronicles

From years of fighting Apophis in his prision should Bast be able to easily defeat Apophis in the kane Chronicles

Comment: Because she knows how Apophis fights? Well, maybe, but the converse is also true: Apophis knows how Bast fights.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason, why she would.

1. As @Adamant commented it works both ways. They both learn about how each other fights effectively staying on the same relative skills.
2. As she says herself "Your[Kanes'] mother saw me losing the fight." Bast wasn't matching Apophis. Just good enough to keep him busy as long as he couldn't escape.
3. Apophis was gathering followers and supporters(Mienszykow, demons and so on...), she wasn't. It's his advantage. Unless you count Kanes' and their students in. Then, that's what she did - defeated Apophis with them. She was an important part of the final battle...